# Laravel test if the response contains errors?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm working on a legacy code and trying to use tests to cover the code for later refactoring. In one controller there's a piece of code like this:

```php
return redirect()->route('login')->withErrors(['invalid credentials']);
```

Here are my assertions for the test:

```php
$response->assertRedirect(route('login'));
$response->assertSessionHasErrors([
    0 => 'invalid credentials'
]);
```

But the problem is I get the following output:

```sh
Session missing error: 'invalid credentials'
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Any idea how can I get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code of `assertSessionHasErrors()` I think it cannot be done with your use case. The problem is the unnamed array in your `withErrors(...)` method. I see two options for you:

- Change your legacy application into:

```php
return redirect()->route('login')->withErrors(['error' => 'invalid credentials']);
```

Afterwards you can run your test like so:

```php
$response->assertRedirect(route('login'));    
$response->assertSessionHasErrors([
    'error' => 'invalid credentials'
]);
```

- If you cannot change your legacy application you could use this:

```php
$response->assertRedirect(route('login'));    
$this->assertEquals(session('errors')->getBag('default')->first(),'invalid credentials');
```